# How to run a python file in c++ qt project using mac

Tags: c++, qt

I want to call the `show.py` in my Qt project. The `p_stdout` should be `hello`, but I just get an empty string `""`, the `exit code` is 1, and the `exit status` is `QProcess::NormalExit`.

This is my `MainWindow.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // judge
    connect(ui->btnJudge,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::judgeReal1);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::judgeReal1()
{
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    QString pyPath=QString::fromStdString("/Users/limenglin/Documents/CODE/pythonProject/rfm-dcl/show.py");
    params<<pyPath;
    p.start("python3", params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
    qDebug()<<p_stdout;
    qDebug() << "Exit code:" << p.exitCode();
    qDebug() << "Exit status:" << p.exitStatus();
}
```

This is my `show.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello")
```

Comment: Terminology: it's not "call", it is "execute" or just "run".

Comment: Does the command `python3 /Users/limenglin/Documents/CODE/pythonProject/rfm-dcl/show.py` work if you run it from command prompt?

Comment: Exit code 1 is generally an error, 0 would be success. What gives that exit code? The python3 interpreter?

Comment: yes, it works when i run it from command prompt; python3 interpreter gives the exit code

Comment: Check the ```p.error()``` and make sure you can find ```python3``` in one of directories in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Use this to be able to see the error output also: `p.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give exact path to python exe.

A simple example:

```
QString path_python_exe = "/path/to/your/python.exe";


void MainWindow::judgeReal1(){
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()){
        params << "qrc:/blurring_kernel.py" << fileName;
        p.start(path_python_exe, params);
        p.waitForFinished(-1);
    }
}
```

In this case the file blurring_kernel.py takes a parameter, named fileName.

Answer (score 0):

According to screamingeagles's method，I add a exact path to python

```
QString path_python="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3";
```

This is my final `MainWindow.cpp`:

```
void MainWindow::judgeReal1()
{
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    QString path_python="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3";
    QString pyPath=QString::fromStdString("/Users/limenglin/Documents/CODE/pythonProject/rfm-dcl/show.py");
    params<<pyPath;
    p.start(path_python, params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
    qDebug()<<p_stdout;
    qDebug() << "Exit code:" << p.exitCode();
    qDebug() << "Exit status:" << p.exitStatus();
    qDebug()<<"Exit Error:"<<p.error();
}
```

Now, I can get the python file's print